# MS Graph event - keep custom attributes when event moved between calendars

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

As the title says, we are using the MS Graph API to interact with a users events. We need to store some custom data with the event so that our system can handle the events correctly.

After reading the documentation, we successfully implemented the Open Type Extensions, however, we have noticed that there is a significant limitation with this - if the event is moved by a user to a different calendar or another users calendar, then this custom data is lost!

I notice that there are schema extensions and also outlook extended properties, but the documentation does not state whether I am going to have the same issue with these options.

Does anyone know how or if it's possible to achieve what we are trying to do. I would have though this is a pretty essential feature for custom data...!

Thanks in advance